# Add product specific messages on a WooCommerce 'Thank You' page.

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a couple products that require additional information once they've been purchased. How can I display a simple message if a specific product has been purchased? Additionally, I'd like to display a simple message if a a product within the order belongs to a specific product category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you a message if an item from a specific product category is purchased:

```
function so_28348735_category_based_thank_you_message ( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $show = false;

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // check if a product is in specific category
        if ( has_term( 'your_product_category', 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $show = true;
            continue;
        }
    }

    if( $show ){
        echo 'your custom message';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'so_28348735_category_based_thank_you_message' );
```

Untested though, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: This worked for me! WooCommerce Version 5.4.2 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/slash1andy/970f81db419eb01c9761#file-gistfile1-php).

This snippet will enable you to redirect users to a specific page if product X was purchased.

You can have multiple if-statements here if you have more than one product you'd like to have a custom redirection page for.

Comment: Yeah, I think this will work. Thanks. I just need to figure out how to move it from the bottom of page to the top.

Comment: @CraigFowler Sorry - What do you mean by "move it from the bottom to the top"? - If you're able to explain, I may be able to advise. :)

Comment: — Apologies for not being more clear. That code snippet (as well as the snippet helgatheviking posted) places the conditional message below the billing address, which is at the bottom of the page. Does that make sense?